# unable to set execute permission for newly created file in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

i have read most of the answers for the above question and acted likewise,. but still i am struggling to set execute permission for a newly created file in ubuntu.

could anybody please help me in getting this.

below are the steps which i used but still failed.

1. `umask` is set to `0000`
2. `setfacl output`

```
xxxxx@xxxxxx:/share/Reference$ getfacl /share/Reference/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: share/Reference/
# owner: root
# group: share
# flags: -s-
# user::rwx
# group::rwx
# other::rwx
# default:user::rwx
# default:group::rwx
# default:group:share:rwx
# default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx

# out put of new create file permission

# xxxxx@xxxxxx:/share/Reference$ ll
# total 12
# drwxrwsrwx+ 3 root    share 4096 Feb  8 11:29 ./
# drwxrwxrwx  5 root    root  4096 Feb  8 10:34 ../
# drwxrwsrwx+ 2 tcadmin share 4096 Feb  8 11:18 k2/
# -rw-rw-rw-+ 1 tcadmin share    0 Feb  8 11:29 k3
```

Comment: Created *where*? is `share` a remote filesystem? if so, what type and how is it mounted?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whom you want to give execute permissions i.e. current user, group or all users.

The chmod command helps you do it based on the options you give it.

```
 chmod u+x filename: gives permission to current user
 chmod +x filename: gives execute permission to all users on the system.
```